# PC reboots at random times

Tags: hp-desktop-computer

I hadn't used the computer for about a month, when I turned it on it worked fine for a day or two. Then it started to spontaneously reboot itself.

It's at a stage now where sometimes Windows doesn't even load before it reboots, other times it will run for an hour.

I have no idea how to debug this, can any one provide any suggestions so I can at least start my own research.

Comment: Please give us more information. Anything would help...

Comment: Start in Safe mode !

Comment: @Buscar웃, how would starting this in safe mode help to rule out if the fault is motherboard or PSU?

Comment: Edited question to try and make it more understandable, if you don't like it roll it back @Braden.

Comment: The question is what is rebooting the computer. At this time we do not know if motherboard or PSU is at fault, but it could be a software.

Answer (score 3):

Although either is possible, both seem unlikely. In my personal experience (decades doing repair work) a PS rarely fails without giving some kind of advance indication. To rule it out, see if you can borrow one from a friend. Most PS are fairly standardized, and unless you go for something elaborate, not too expensive.

Before you get into changing parts, however, there is another culprit I have seen many times, especially in systems rarely used: loose add-on cards. If your computer has a separate video card (instead of on-board) take it out and "re-seat" it back in again. Then try the boot. If that makes no difference, do the same with any other add-on cards.

It's also useful to note the EXACT point at which the system reboots. Is it always exactly the same point in the start up cycle, or does it vary? That can help find the issue if you can determine what is happening at the point of failure. Be sure to try and get into Safe Mode if you can.

Assuming all the above fails, there is a free Windows utility called [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) which is one of the most useful I've found for diagnostic work. It boots your computer through one of the usual Linux-loaded Windows XP implementations. The point of this is since the Windows OS is not loaded, you'll at least find out if its the PC that's going down, or the OS (Windows).

You'll need to set your boot priority in your BIOS for "CD First" and of course, you'll need a friend's PC to download and make the startup disc for you. Just Google "Hiren's Boot CD" and you'll find it.

Comment: And while you are inside the case reseating hardware, clean out any dust and make sure your cpu fan is spinning.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mark's answer is great, so I'll try to add other suggestions.

As mark said, borrow a PSU and test it.
As Scandalist said in Mark's comments, make sure it's free of dust and dirt.
Turn the PC on with the side case off and make sure all fans are spinning.
Load up the BIOS screen and make sure it's not overheating (some BIOS will report fan speeds and CPU heat).
If you can get onto the machine, download a SMART tool ([Acronis is free](http://www.acronis.co.uk/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor/)) and check the hard drive.
Open it up, ensure all connections are properly connected and RAM is well seated.
Take out all but 1 RAM and test it.
Download a program like WhosCrashed to see if that sheds any light.
View the event logs on the machine to see if that suggests anything
Ensure nothing is over heating